# Converting multiple Excel .xls files to .xlsx format

Tags: excel, automation

I am searching for a simple way to convert many .xls files contained within the path 'C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Results' into .xlsx format 
I have Excel 2013 installed, but I would like for there to be a way to automatically convert any files that get placed within that folder.

I am unsure if it possible for me to execute this by simply putting some code into the command line or if it would require me to download other resources in order for this to be possible.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not on topic on Stack Overflow, which is for very specific, technical programming questions. A Google search for `Converting multiple Excel .xls files to .xlsx format` seems to be getting good results though.

Comment: If you are familiar with .NET (C#, VB.NET, Powershell), I would use a `FileSystemWatcher` and Excel Interop. If you want to use WSH, you'll need some sort of loop together with `WScript.Sleep`. VBA doesn't really make sense here, because the document/workbook/presentation that would contain the VBA would always have to be open.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The OP wants some sort of listener running in the background, not just to convert multiple files. Isn't that more on-topic?

Comment: @Zev not really. They're looking for an application, not a programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, something like this:

```
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Results");
fsw.Created += (s,e) => {
    if (!e.FullPath.EndsWith(".xls")) {return;}
    var newName = e.FullPath.Remove(e.FullPath.Length-3) + "xlsx";
    var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    var book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(e.FullPath);
    book.SaveAs(newName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel12);
    xlApp.Quit();
};
```